# Initialize / activate SQL prior to GET DIAGNOSTICS

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have two service programs: mySrvPgm and myErr

mySrvPgm has a procedure which contains:

```
/free
  ...
  exec sql INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES(:RECORD_FMT);
  if sqlError() = *ON;
    //handle error
  endif;
  ...
/end-free
```

myErr has a procedure sqlError:

```
/free
  exec sql GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 
    :state = RETURNED_SQLSTATE;
  ...
/end-free
```

*Background info:* I am using XMLSERVICE to call the given procedure in mySrvPgm from PHP. I am not using a persistent connection. myErr is bound-by-reference via a binding directory used by mySrvPgm. Its activation is set to `*IMMED`, its activation group is set to `*CALLER`.

**The problem:** Assume there is an error on the INSERT statement in mySvrPgm. The first time `sqlError()` is called it will return `SQLSTATE 00000` despite the error. All subsequent calls to `sqlError()` return the expected SQLSTATE.

**A workaround:** I added a procedure to myErr called initSQL:

```
/free
  exec sql SET SCHEMA MYLIB;
/end-free
```

If I call `initSQL()` before the INSERT statement in mySrvPgm, `sqlError()` functions correctly. It doesn't have to be `SET SCHEMA`, it can be another `GET DIAGNOSTICS` statement. However, if it does not contain an executable SQL statement it does not help.

**The question:** I believe the myErr service program is activating properly and has the correct scope, but I am wondering if there is something more I need to do to activate the SQL part of it. Is there some way to set it up so SQL auto-initializes when the service program is activated, or do I have to execute an unneeded SQL statement in order to get it started?

There is some more background information available [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=d2c49b79-5a01-46f7-9a11-b9de0f2b0e02#3b47a829-e864-44db-99c4-653a7547add2).

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version an release of the OS?  Are you upto date on PTFs?

Honestly, seems to me that it's possibly a bug.  Or the manual(s) need clarification.. I'd open a PMR.